# Python program to copy files from one folder to another; PermissionError [Errno 13]

Tags: python, windows

I have written a small python program to help me find all .mp3 files in a definite directory and then copy them to a desired directory.

I have executed the program from the Administrator Command Promt but this has not worked for me. Do you have any suggestions?

This is the error I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Users\Martin\Desktop\copyMusic.py", line 11, in <module>
    copyfile(datoteka, destination)

  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64\lib\shutil.py", line 121, in copyfile
    with open(dst, 'wb') as fdst:

PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'Desired Location To Copy The Files To'
```

Here is the code:

#

```
import glob

from shutil import copyfile

import time


destination = "Desired Location To Copy The Files To"

files = glob.glob("FolderWithTheMusicFiles/*.mp3")

for file in files:

    copyfile(file, destination)
```

#

Thank you all for your time and effort!

Comment: Maybe the target destination does not exist? I have no clue about how Windows behaves in this case though.

Comment: The error is telling us that the path you have assigned to `destination` is not a valid destination. the signature for [shutil.copyfile](https://docs.python.org/2/library/shutil.html#shutil.copyfile): `shutil.copyfile(src, dst)` says that "`src` and `dst` are path names given as strings.",  so you need to replace `"Desired Location To Copy The Files To"` with an ***actual*** path like `destination = "C://MyUser/MyMusicFiles"` or whatever desination directory you desire to copy the files ***to***

Comment: The destination for [`copyfile`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html#shutil.copyfile) (Python 3 link) has to be a filename. The error is from trying to open a directory as a regular file.